# How to check if two elements inside two array have the same index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, frontend

I am new to javascript and want to know if there is a possible method to find out if an element inside an array has the same index as another element inside another array.

For example :

```
var a = [4,6,3]
var b = [6,6,0]
```

how can I find out if the elements at index 1 in both arrays are the same in Javascript or using jQuery?

I cannot figure this and and any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: hint: `a.map((_, n) => a[n] === b[n])` will return `[false,true,false]` for your example.

Comment: It helps to scribble on a paper some logic and then try to implement it in code. If you realize you need to loop something, then you go google for loops in JavaScript. Then try to investigate on those design elements on Google, and in the end build something by yourself. Also we're expecting to see some minimal effort, please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve] of your best code and a specific issue. PS. no, you don't need jQuery.

Comment: Shahab, if you're new to javascript you have a golden opportunity to learn well. Forget about jquery and everything else except basic programming concepts and javascript syntax. Learn how to access array elements and about comparison operators and you will solve this yourself, More importantly you will learn to programme. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Before learning those easy-to-use methods, I'm personally think you should learn to solve it in a very basic way first

```
let index = -1; // -1 normally defined as not found

for (let i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
 for (let j = 0 ; j < b.length ; j++) {
  if (a[i] === b[j]) {
   index = i; // or index = j; is the same
  } // we won't need else since we don't need to do anything when the numbers are not match
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for the "magical" JS  way,

`a.some((i,j) => i == b[j])` should do what you're asking.

The `some` command runs a function across every element of the array and checks if any of them are true. The function parameters `i` is the value of the elements in the first array and `j` is the index. We use the `j` to get the value of `b` at that point and check if it's equal.